# invert array using SVD function in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to get the inverse of the R array of shape (3,2) using the svd method

```
R = [[190.93095651 189.30517758]
 [187.01785506 185.38861727]
 [183.29225361 181.47205695]]
```

I tried the following

```
u, s, vh = np.linalg.svd(r, full_matrices=True)

vh_1 = np.transpose(vh)
u_1 = np.transpose(u)
s_1 = np.transpose(s)
Rv = (u_1 * s_1) *vh_1
```

The shape of the resulted matrix RV is (2, 2, 3) I expected to get a (2,3) dimension array instead
I want to proceed with the RV array and multiply it with (2,1) array A

```
A = [-0.20434669 -0.20225446]
print(np.dot(np.transpose(Rv),A))
```

And i expect a (3,1) array as a result. However I got a (3,2) array instead.

Comment: [`np.linalg.pinv`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.pinv.html)?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I already used this way but i need to compare it with the result from the svd method